# Rで0.17 * 10000 == 1700がFALSEになる理由と解消法

Tags: r

タイトルの通りなのですが，Rで0.17 * 10000 == 1700の真偽を判定させると，FALSEが返ってきます。以下はTRUEと判定されます（当然ですが…）。
1700 * 1 == 1700
170 * 10 == 1700
17 * 100 == 1700
1.7 * 1000 == 1700
Rが正しく計算できていないように見えるにははなぜでしょうか？また解消法はあるでしょうか？
追記：0.28 * 10000 == 2800も同様でした。

Answer (score 3):

help メッセージで言及されています。

```r
$ R

R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing

> ?"=="

                          :
Note:

     Do not use ‘==’ and ‘!=’ for tests, such as in ‘if’
     expressions, where you must get a single ‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’.
     Unless you are absolutely sure that nothing unusual can happen,
     you should use the ‘identical’ function instead.

     For numerical and complex values, remember ‘==’ and ‘!=’ do
     not allow for the finite representation of fractions, nor for
     rounding error.  Using ‘all.equal’ with ‘identical’ or
     ‘isTRUE’ is almost always preferable; see the examples.  (This
     also applies to the other comparison operators.)

                          :
Examples:

     x1 <- 0.5 - 0.3
     x2 <- 0.3 - 0.1
     x1 == x2                   # FALSE on most machines
     isTRUE(all.equal(x1, x2))  # TRUE everywhere
```

なので、以下の様にします。

```r
> isTRUE(all.equal(0.17 * 10000, 1700))
[1] TRUE
```